# Chronograf line chart increase decimal

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I am using Chronograf to analyze some stock data, the original data has 5 decimals, but when they are shown in Chronograf, only 2 decimals are shown:

[image]

How can I set and increase the number of decimals in Chronograf?

Answer (score 0):

Change `DEFAULT_DECIMAL_PLACES`'s property `digits` from 2 to your preferred decimal.

https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/blob/master/ui/src/dashboards/constants/index.ts

Instead of installing the pre-compiled version, you need to follow the GitHub instruction to compile the amended source code in order to have your change being effective.

https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf

Comment: Is there any way to dynamic change the digits without re-compile it? some of the data need to show 3 digits, some others need to show  5 digits